# Porting an Android app as a Web Application

Tags: android, web-applications

Is there a way to port an Android app as a Web Application such that it can run on any device that has an internet connection and a web browser?

I would be glad if someone could give me resources like tutorials or books on this subject.

Comment: To my opinion: (1) This question is really good! Because I have this question, too.(2) The answer is not good! Because, there are many options to build web applications, like e.g. libGDX. Or other game engines, cross-compilers or tool chains could be a solution. Not quite matching, but some further ideas are: Emscripten or Haxe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native Android applications are fundamentally different from Web Applications. It's not possible to port them and it will most likely never be possible to do so.

Comment: Plus 1 for your answer. So we would need to develop the whole thing from scratch for the web application?

Comment: If we're talking about a native Android app, yes you have to develop it from scratch. It is however possible to wrap a web application in an Android app. Kinda like a browser app but it only displays one website. This results in a lower quality app because it's not native (slower, interface usually not as smooth, less possibilities with system integration). However if that's how they build the app it's possible to port that to a web application, reducing costs.